# VK.api js методы getHighScores и setUserScore

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, методы

Хочу узнать работают ли эти методы до сих пор, и как их использовать

Comment: Скорее всего ответ на вопрос лучше искать не здесь, а в документации к VK.api

Comment: Дак вот как раз в документации написано, что эти методы могут устареть и их желательно не использовать. Они мне на долгое время использования не нужны. По этому решил спросить в поддержке вк, но они долго отвечают

Answer (score 0):

Как вы сами здесь уже написали:

> В документации написано, что эти методы могут устареть и их желательно
>   не использовать.

[Хранение данных на серверах ВКонтакте | Справка разработчика ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/page-1_2369990)

Video-уроки «Работа с API VK (Вконтакте) через JavaScript»:

- [Урок 1.](https://youtu.be/bbKvkiz5_uc)
- [Урок 2.](https://youtu.be/fnZNPmTO338)

**Примеры обращения к VK.Api:**

```
VK.Api.call('getHighScores', {}, function(data)
{
    if(!data.error)
    {
        if(data.response && data.response.length > 0)
        {
            console.log(data.response[0].user_id);
        }
    }
});

VK.Api.call('setUserScore', {score: stepsCount}, function(data)
{
    if(data.error)
    {
         console.log(data.error.error_msg);
    }
    else
    {

    }
});
```

[Поиск ответов через Google](https://google.ru/search?q=VK.api%20getHighScores%20setUserScore).

Comment: Меня интересует конкретный вопрос. Работают, либо нет.

Comment: А кто писал "как их использовать?"?

Comment: За наглядный пример вам спасибо. Но больше конечно же интересует вопрос их работоспособности